# Why is there an enlarged Nun in Exodus 34:7?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, aleph-bet-letters, parashat-ki-tisa

> ... keeping mercy for thousands, forgiving iniquity and transgressions and sin.

In some Torah scrolls, the Nun in the word נצר "keeping" is written larger than normal. What is the significance of this enlarged Nun?

[image: "נצר חסד לאלפים, נשא עון ופשע וחטאה" in Torah script, with an enlarged 'nun']
<sup>Excerpted from the Beverly Hills Chabad [Torah Reading page](http://www.beverlyhillschabad.com/torah-reading/torah-reading-player.htm)</sup>

[image: Exodus 34:7 in a Chumash, including an enlarged 'nun'.]
<sup>[Excerpted](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9596&st=&pgnum=560&hilite=) from [*Chumash Mikros Gedolos Shemos*](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/9596), Romm Brothers, New York, 1935, found on HebrewBooks.org</sup>

Comment: [I don't see a large nun there on pg 339](http://www.nteiman.co.il/tort_amt/2/9.pdf) (and they do mark big letters, as can be seen in the ר on page 342)

Comment: @DoubleAA See http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9596&st=&pgnum=560&hilite= I've seen this in most Tikkunim as well as most sifrei Torah that I have read from.

Comment: BA, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for bringing your question here! I look forward to seeing you around.

Comment: @DoubleAA [This source](http://www.soferstam.co.il/content.aspx?PageId=46&lang=he) (whoever it is) lists this one and says that Teimanim don't do it.

Comment: @IsaacMoses That sounds pretty accurate to me (whoever I am). Did you see where my first source is from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I don't recall where I saw this (it could have been in the commentary of the Komarna Rebbe to the Torah) The enlarged Nun found in 34:7 is connected to the enlarged Resh which follows it in 34:14. Together they form the word 'Ner' (נר).

In context of the end of the parsha, this seems to be alluding to the light which radiated from Moshe's face at the conclusion of this event in posukim 34:29-30.

And this would be in keeping with the expression of the Sages, z"l (Mishlei 20:27), "The candle of G-d is the soul of man." **(נר ה׳ נשמת אדם)**

And because of that light, the Jewish people were afraid of Moshe and moved away from him. But Moshe called the leaders of the generation back and gave them a new, additional mission (called *shlichut* in Hebrew) like is found in [note 20 of Siftei Chochamim to Rashi on 34:31](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9596&st=&pgnum=570). That mission was to teach the entire Torah and all the mitzvot to the Jewish people and that this should be an occupation every day.

And this corresponds to a second expression from our Sages (Mishlei 6:23), "A candle is a mitzvah and Torah is light." **(נר מצוה ותורה אור)**

Comment: Do you ordinary refer to King Solomon as "the Sages"? I've never seen that use before, and certainly the plural seems odd.

Comment: Shlomo HaMelech counts as one of the sages of Israel. And many other sages of Israel repeat his teaching.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. The nun with the resh forming the word "ner" completes the thought in verses 29-30.

Answer (score 3):

The [Shelah HaKadosh (Maseches Yoma, hilchos teshuva)](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14406&st=&pgnum=335&hilite=) says that this enlarged nun is an allusion to the *nachash* that enticed mankind to sin. At the time of egel hazahav the yetzer hara became too strong that it was capable to influence *Am yisroel* to do *avodah zarah*. The large letter nun, in this sense, is to call attention to this fact by saying that Hashem (and only Him) can forgive our sins.

Answer (score -1):

The following response provides an *indirect* response to the original question and concludes with the relationship to Exodus 34:7 (i.e., the verse in question).

In the *[Leningrad Codex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leningrad_Codex)* the Masoretes recognized only **one** enlarged *nun* in Scripture, which is found in the last letter of the word "משפט**ן**" in Numbers 27:5.  (The margin note of the Masoretic Text states "ל̇ נון רב̇," which means, "one occurrence of the enlarged *nun*.")

Please click the below image in order to view the source document online.

[image: This hyperlink provides a direct view of the Masoretic leaf of the Codex Leningrad for Numbers 27:5.]

However, when we view the same passage from the Dead Sea Scrolls, there is no apparent large *nun* evident. In other words, the enlarged *nun* in the Masoretic Text appears to be a later editorial addition for special emphasis.

Please click the below image in order to view the source document online.

[image: This hyperlink provides a direct view of the Dead Sea Scrolls for Numbers 27:5.]

According to Yeivin (1980), there are three reasons for large letters in the Masoretic Text:

> 1) the letter stands at the beginning of a book or at the beginning of a new section;
>   2) the letter draws attention to a significant statistical point, e.g., the large letter in Lev. 11:42 marks the middle of the Torah in letters; and
>   3) the letter shows that the reading must be precise.

As in the case in Exodus 34:7 (where Midrash appears to have added the large *nun*) the sole appearance of the only enlarged *nun* in Numbers 27:5 may have been to provide **unequivocal emphasis** that the case which Moses brought before the Lord was on behalf of women. That is, the emphasis was that for the first time in the Torah, the rights and claims of women came before the Lord.

---

**Reference:**

Yeivin, Israel (1980). [*Introduction to the Tiberian Masorah*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/089130374X). Trans. and Ed. E. J. Revell. "Masoretic Studies," No. 5. Missoula: Scholars Press, 47–48, #84.

Comment: The question already acknowledged that not all scrolls have it. The question was about those that do.

Comment: Are you suggesting, as your eventual answer to the question at hand, that the large nun in Exodus 34:7 has something to do with women? If so, please make it clearer what you mean by that. It seems like a bit of a stretch.

Comment: Also, how does your suggestion regarding the meaning of the large nun, that it has to do with thematic emphasis, related to the universe of possible reasons that you cite from Yeivin? None of them have to do with thematic emphasis.

Comment: @IsaacMoses - I had two points in mind: (1) rabbinic scholars before the 10th Cent did not recognize the enlarged _nun_ in Exodus 34:7; and (2) the significance of the enlarged _nun_ was equivalent to an underline in English (to highlight something important). The appearance of the enlarged _nun_ in Exodus 34:7 had its roots in medieval Midrash, and the purpose (in keeping with tradition) was to provide emphasis. So while I did not attempt to address the question (since Yaacov Deane provided an excellent answer) my intent was to provide information to appreciate the context of the question.