# Large Nun in Num 27:5

Tags: aleph-bet-letters, safrus, pinchas

> וַיַּקְרֵב מֹשֶׁה אֶת מִשְׁפָּטָ**ן** לִפְנֵי יְהוָה.‏

I've seen the ן letter in Number 27:5 (above) is written enlarged (Nun Rabati (Great)).

Why is that?

Comment: I've only seen webpage sources, but it seems there's two possible reasons.  One is that the nun, having a gematria of 50, represents the 50 gates of understanding.  Even though it's a final nun, the original paleo-Hebrew alphabet had no final forms of letters. The other reason seems to be that it draws attention to the fact that it's a ruling about women, and that it's absolutely a nun, grammatically making it a feminine plural word. In the Leningrad Codex it's enlarged, as the 2nd answer for the question about the larger nun in netzer elsewhere on MY says, but not enlarged in the DS Scrolls,

Comment: Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/78443/why-is-there-an-enlarged-nun-in-exodus-347